# What is the main purpose of orderingValue? (ref: iOS programming - big nerd ranch)

Tags: ios, core-data

What is the purpose of orderingValue? Is it just to re-order the fields in the BNRItemStore and the database?

If so, is this needed in all the other entities that are created?

Answer (score 0):

orderValuing is just a step for this particular exercise to order the items